# Automatically updating a blogger page?

Tags: blogger

This bit of code will make a new blogger post.  What can I do to update (not create) an existing page (not post)?

```
curl -v --request POST -H "Content-Type: application/atom+xml" \
    -H "Authorization: GoogleLogin auth=$AUTH" \
    http://www.blogger.com/feeds/$FEED/pages/default --data @blog_post.xml
```